# How to get value of input field dynamically which is added by an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a document which has two parts that are dynamically filled in by Ajax calls. In that call are a couple of input fields. I must store the contents of those fields in a database.

The problem is that I can't get the values from the input fields. Instead of the value I get a long text with a complete function like below:

```
function(e){var t,n,r,i=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return r=g(e),this.each(function(n){var i;1===this.nodeType&&(null==...
```

I made a simplified version of my code, but with the same problem:

Main code: (main.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>main program</h2>
        
        <input type="button" id="btnBanner" value="Banner">
        <input type="button" id="btnAR" value="AR-object" >
        <div id="banner"> 
            <h3>Banner</h3>
            Nothing to see here
        </div>
        <div id="ar">
            <form>
            <h3>Object</h3>
            <div id="existingOBJ" >              
            </div>
            <div id="OBJlocation"></div>
            <input type="button" id="btnSaveAR" value="Save-object" >
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
                $('#banner').show();
                $('#ar').hide();
                $('#SaveObjectButton').hide;

                $(function() {
                    $('#btnBanner').click(function() {
                        $('#banner').show();
                        $('#ar').hide();
                    });
                
                    $('#btnAR').click(function() {
                        $('#banner').hide();
                        $('#ar').show();
                        $.ajax({
                            type    : "POST",
                            url     : 'existingobj.php',        
                            data    : {
                                'id'    : 104,
                                'objID' : 7
                            },
                            dataType: "html",
                        })                        
                        .done(function (result) {                        
                            $("#existingOBJ").html(result);
                            $.ajax({
                                type    : "POST",
                                url     : 'existingloc.php',        
                                data    : {
                                    'id'    : 104,
                                    'objID' : 7
                                },
                                dataType: "html",
                            })                        
                            .done(function (resultLoc) {                        
                                $("#OBJlocation").html(resultLoc);
                            })
                        
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        
            $(document.body).on("click",'#btnSaveAR', function() {
                alert('save object');
                dummy = $('#rotate_x').val;
                alert('rotate_x = '+dummy);
            })
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Existingobj.php

```
<html>
    <style>
        .cl-number {
            width: 64px;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <?php
            $x=0;
            $y=20;
            $z=90;
            $elv =1.5;
        ?>
        <table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid;">
            <tr><td width="10%"></td><td width="20%"></td><td width="70%"></td></tr>
            <tr><th>UserID </th><td> <?php echo $_REQUEST['id'];?> </td><td colspan="">Example</td></tr>
            <tr><th>objectID </th><td> <?php echo $_REQUEST['objID'];?> </td></tr>
            <tr><th>Rotation X-axis </th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="rotate_x" id="rotate_x" value="<?php echo $x; ?>" min="0" max="360" step="10" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><th>Rotation Y-axis </th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="rotate_y" id="rotate_y" value="<?php echo $y; ?>" min="0" max="360" step="10" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><th>Rotation Z-axis </th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="rotate_x" id="rotate_z" value="<?php echo $z; ?>" min="0" max="360" step="10" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><th>Elevation</th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="elevation" id="elevation" value="<?php echo $elv; ?>" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

existingloc.php

```
<html>
    <style>
        .cl-number {
            width: 64px;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <?php
            $lat=52.090164;
            $long= 5.358045;
            
        ?>
        <table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid;">
            <tr><td width="10%"></td><td width="20%"></td><td width="10%"></td><td width="20%"></td><td width="40%"></td></tr>
            
            <tr><th>Rotation X-axis </th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="lat" id="lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" min="0" max="360" step="10" ></td>
                <th>Rotation Y-axis </th>
                <td> <input type="number" class="cl-number" name="long" id="long" value="<?php echo $long; ?>" min="0" max="360" step="10" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><th colspan="5">Little map is drawn here</th>
            
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect the issue might be around inserting full HTML documents into elements. Have you tried to not including HTML or BODY tags in the files that are loaded via AJAX?

Comment: I'm confused. Where do you see that function?

Comment: @Adam H I tried it without the HTML and BODY tags, but the result is the same. The function is the contents of one of the fields (Rotate-x) displayed in the alert in the main-code. I need the real content.

Comment: For the time being I used a workaround and used the on change events of every item. This creates extra database alterations, which I wanted to prevent.